# MySQL always overwrite existing database entry (UPDATE, REPLACE, INSERT ????)

Tags: php, mysql, replace, insert

I would like to always replace the same existing database entry.

The following code always creates a new entry, How do I have to modify that it always overwrites "version"?

```
$sql = "REPLACE INTO `traumprojekt` 
            (`version`, `geschlecht`, `alter`, `fuehrerschein`)

        VALUES(
            '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
            '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
            " .$alter. ",
            " .$fuehrerschein. "
            )";

mysql_query( $sql );
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I understood the question but why don't you use UPDATE command ?

Comment: I'm a complete noob, how can I use UPDATE?

Comment: `UPDATE SET <fields> WHERE id = <rowId>` is a basic outline on how to use it

Comment: He can't just use UPDATE, because if the line does not exist, UPDATE won't create a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

REPLACE is just an insert, that will "delete" the old row before adding a new.

It can only determine an "old" row if there are constraints that mark the new row as "existing".

Your replace statement is OK, but **you should add a UNIQUE INDEX** on `geschlecht`, `alter`, `fuehrerschein` so it can just change the version.

An alternative can be [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), but you also need a unique key there. The difference is that REPLACE does a DELETE, then INSERT; while INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE does an UPDATE instead of the INSERT. It matters with for example triggers...

Comment: It would be geat if you can make an example with my code, I'm pretty new to this stuff

Comment: Your code is fine, your database is not. You need a [UNIQUE INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) on your table.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would use UPDATE instead. For example:

```
REPLACE INTO `traumprojekt` 
  (`version`, `geschlecht`, `alter`, `fuehrerschein`)
VALUES(
  '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
  '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
  " .$alter. ",
  " .$fuehrerschein. "
)
WHERE
  /* Your condition here */;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a unique key on some of the columns. This way the script will insert once when there is no data and then will update when the column key duplicates. Lets say you create an unique index on the version column:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `traumprojekt` 
        (`version`, `geschlecht`, `alter`, `fuehrerschein`)

    VALUES(
        '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
        '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
        " .$alter. ",
        " .$fuehrerschein. "
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        `geschlecht`='" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
        `alter`=" .$alter. ", `fuehrerschein`= " .$fuehrerschein;
```

Or, if you want to have only one record in your table, then you can create an unique column called Id as TinyINT and base your logic on it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `traumprojekt` 
        (`id`,`version`, `geschlecht`, `alter`, `fuehrerschein`)

    VALUES(1,
        '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
        '" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
        " .$alter. ",
        " .$fuehrerschein. "
        ) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        `version`='" .mysql_real_escape_string( $version ). "',
        `geschlecht`='" .mysql_real_escape_string( $geschlecht ). "',
        `alter`=" .$alter. ", `fuehrerschein`= " .$fuehrerschein;
```

MySQL docs here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: first code is working, but still creates new entries. second code doesn't work for me